# How can I enable IntelliSense on a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I need to *know* how to add **IntelliSense** to a VS Code extension. I tried nothing because that's what I do when I don't know how to do something. Can I please *know* how?

**Thanks! :D**

Comment: write a `CompletionItemProvider` and `HoverProvider`

Comment: But how do I write it??

Comment: read the VSC extension writer guide, there are many example extensions that will help you to use the API